# GCM service - dynamic text

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

1) i would like to implement dynamic text feature in my server side (java - using GCM) - that mean that i need to custom the push body data to every device but i still want to push to multiple devices at one time. 
(using   multicastResult = sender.send(mess, devicePushTokenList, 3);

any body knows a way to do it in derver side? (i know a way to do it in the device time before the push arrives)

2) i know apple has a feedback service that i can run in any given time + the feedback of the push response.  does GCM has this service too?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multicast messaging, you will unfortunately need to send the same message.

One solution (which I don't really like) would be to have your app request data from your server upon receiving the message and updating the message appropriately.

You're better off sending messages to each device individually.

Answer (score 0):

1. As the other answer stated, multicast requires all the messages to be identical.
2. GCM doesn't have a Feedback Service, and it doesn't need to have one, since it returns an immediate response for each pushed message, and one of the error statuses - `NotRegistered` - covers the case of devices that uninstalled the app (which is what Apple's Feedback Service is for).